# How can I ignore a specific factor level when running a GLMER in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mixed-models, factors

I am running a common RSF to evaluate landcover type usage by GPS collared deer. I have a factor column named Landcover_Type populated with numbers 1-5 which correspond to a specific landcover type (i.e., 2 = woody, 3 = herbaceous, 4 = water, etc.). How can I exclude water from being considered in my model?

[image: Sample Data]

The code below specifies the factor level to use as a reference and the model runs beautifully. However, I need to remove water from consideration.

```
levels(pre_RSFpoints$Landcover_Type) 
pre_RSFpoints<-within(pre_RSFpoints, Landcover_Type <-relevel(Landcover_Type, ref = 2))

pre_model <- glmer(Used ~ Landcover_Type + (1|Id),family="binomial",data=pre_RSFpoints)
summary(pre_model)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please edit your question to show that you are sharing your data snippet as text (probably in a code block format, i.e. with triple-backticks) rather than as an image? Images are unsearchable and inaccessible to people using screen readers.

Comment: I'm curious that if you want to keep other variables of samples with `Landcover_type` is `water`. If not, just remove those samples.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ben Bolker, I can't figure out how to share the data as text. I copy and pasted it from an excel file and have tried several different ways to prevent it from being attached as an image.

Comment: Park, I have contemplated removing water all together because I would rather include distance to water as a variable. However, I am not ready to commit and would rather not remove water all together just yet.

Comment: I've concluded that I don't understand the question. I can't see a way to "remove water from consideration" that is different from removing the observations with Landcover_Type == water from the data set ...

Comment: Ben Bolker, I have GPS locations that are in one of the following: woody cover, grasslands, bare ground, caliche, and water. I do not want the few GPS locations in water to have any affect on my model, therefore I want to exclude them from consideration. I can go remove any GPS locations that are in water from the data set. However, I did not want to do that at the moment. Your recommendation accomplished exactly what I wanted to do. I will likely remove water from the data set all together and include distance to water as a covariate because I think that would be a better approach. Thank you

Comment: If my answer solved your problem then you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to create a new data frame:

```r
pre_model_nowater <- subset(pre_model, Landcover_Type != "4"))
```

you can use the `subset=` argument within `glmer`:

```r
pre_model <- glmer(Used ~ Landcover_Type + (1|Id),   
    family="binomial", data=pre_RSFpoints,
    subset = (Landcover_Type != "4"))
```

By the way, you should be **extremely** careful when using factors that have numbers as their levels. Before you relevel, the correspondence between values ("1"="something"=1, "2"="woody"=2, "3"="herbaceous"=3) is sensible, but afterwards it will get scrambled ("2" will be the first level, "1" the second level), and you may mess things up if you refer to factors by their integer codes.  If possible it would be better practice to retain the character strings as labels ...

If the data come to you with numeric codes, the best way to deal with is to transform them back to text labels as soon as you have read in the data, with `transform()` (base R) or `mutate()` (tidyverse), e.g.

```r
pre_model <- transform(pre_model,
    Landcover_Type = factor(Landcover_Type, levels = 1:5,
              labels = c("something", "woody", "herbaceous", ...)))
```

Also, if you are doing a habitat preference analysis you should probably read [this thread](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/744), which refers to [this journal article](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1365-2656.13087).

Comment: Thanks Ben Bolker, and I completely agree with the dangers of using factor numbers. When extracting values to points from my classified landcover raster, I am left with only the number to represent the landcover type and I have not figured out the best way to handle it. I guess I could extract values then immediately add a reference column specifying what each factor number represents.